# Photoshop script to export layer combinations

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, photoshop-script

I want to make a Photoshop script that lets me export all five layers in a group to a png file
- in combination with every single layer from 2 other groups.

> It's a bit vague so I'll try to illustrate what I want to
>   accomplish.   There's the base group (red, blue, yellow, orange,
>   green). Then there is a second group that contains layers 1,2 and 3.
>   Then there's a third group that contains a, b, c and d.
>
> I want to
>   be able to export 1_red_a.png, 1_red_b.png, 1_red_c.png, 1_red_d.png,
>   1_blue_a.png, 1_blue_b.png, ...

I don't have much experience with Photoshop scripts. Is this something that can be accomplished? And if so, is anyone prepared to help me?

Comment: What do you mean by *"in combination with"*? Side by side? Luminosity overlay? Do you really want 60 output images? What OS are you using? How about providing a sample image?

Comment: I'm not at home right now, so providing sample images isn't really possible right now. I am however working on Windows and I would indeed like alot of output files. What I mean with in combination is just that I want them to be visible at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have got the idea of what you want. I find ExtendScript pretty awkward to code in and would tend to do automated stuff outside of Photoshop with more powerful, everyday tools. I would go with ImageMagick and `bash`. ImageMagick is free and available for Windows, and the basic command to composite two images on top of one another is

```
convert image1.png image2.png -composite result.png
```

Of course you can change any or all of the `PNG` suffices to `TIF`, `JPG` or whatever you like.

So, for your question, I have made a sample file with a couple of Groups to show the concept, like this:

[image]

The Photoshop file is avilable [here](http://thesetchells.com/image.psd).

Zoom into the `Layers` palette (on the right in the above image) to see the 2 groups I made.

Then go to File->Scripts->Export Layers to Files, and select the options like this:

[image]

That will export the following files for you:

```
layers_0000s_0002_Layer A.png
layers_0000s_0001_Layer B.png
layers_0000s_0000_Layer C.png       
layers_0001s_0003_Layer 1 - Red.png
layers_0001s_0002_Layer 2 - Green.png
layers_0001s_0001_Layer 3 - Blue.png
layers_0001s_0000_Layer 4 - Magenta.png
```

Note that the format is `xxx<GROUP>s_xxx<LAYER>xxx.png`

Now you can easily create all permutations of the groups with this `bash` script. I presume the Windows BATCH file would be pretty similar - though I only do Windows under duress !!!

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
# Iterate over Group 0 files
for a in *0s_*.png; do
   j=0
   # Iterate over Group 1 files
   for b in *1s_*.png; do
      convert "$a" "$b" -composite out_${i}_${j}.png
      ((j++))
   done
   ((i++))
done
```

which gives you these output files:

```
out_0_0.png
out_0_1.png
out_0_2.png
out_0_3.png
out_1_0.png
out_1_1.png
out_1_2.png
out_1_3.png
out_2_0.png
out_2_1.png
out_2_2.png
out_2_3.png
```

Just for kicks, I put them all together in a montage and you get this:

[image]

Note that if you have 3 groups, you will need a third inner loop in your script, and the command to composite the 3 images together will be more like this (because the `-composite` option takes the two preceding images):

```
convert image1.png image2.png -composite image3.png -composite result.png
```

Alternatively, you may find you can use

```
convert -background none image1.png image2.png image3.png -flatten result.png
```

Comment: Whoa :p thanks for all the effort! I'll try it out when I get home and Let you know if it resulted in success. I don't think i'll have any major problems after your explanation :)

Comment: If you don't have ImageMagick installed, and you download it from here http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php - I would maybe consider using the last one listed - the one with zero installation and zero configuration and then, if you don't like it or want it, you can very simply remove it by deleting the directory you installed it into.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Mark, do you want to add a link to your sample Photoshop file you created for the answer?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Yes, I have made the file available - good suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: I ended up trying to accomplish things another way, Instead of making alot of images I'm now combining them within the application itself. However, it's likely that I'll face a certain problem later on. So this might still come in handy. Thanks for the great support!

Answer (score 1):

[Photoshop Composition Composer](https://github.com/mechanicious/photoshopCompositionComposer) will create compositions of whatever is contained in the top-level `groups`. The the name of a `group` and the `layer` belonging to it joined together will be your file name.

### Usage

1. See the Example and the Preview below to learn how it works
2. Download and unzip `photoshopCompositionComposer` `jsx`-file
3. Open your project and navigate to `File > Scripts > Browse...`
4. Browse and load the downloaded `jsx` file

### Example

**Layers**

- `Group` animals.

  - `Layer` dog_
  - `Group` cat_
- `Group` background.

  - `Layer` sea_
  - `Group` space_
  - `Layer` underWater_

[image]

**Resulting Compositions**

1. animals.dog_background.sea_
2. animals.dog_background.space_
3. animals.dog_background.underWater_
4. animals.cat_background.sea_
5. animals.cat_background.space_
6. animals.cat_background.underWater_

### Preview

[image]