# Programatically resizing individual Groups of a PSD, then rendering them to PNG in C++

Tags: c++, photoshop, psd

I want to know if it is possible to read PSD files from C++, resize 1 specific Group programmatically, then render the result to a PNG. So far I found some code that reads and renders PSD files "as is", here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10398/Import-Adobe-Photoshop-psd-images

The problem I foresee is that just rendering a PSD as is is pretty easy, but resizing Groups programmatically would require much more effort.

Comment: Most PSDs contains a "composite layer", which is what most 3rd party software will display, when it displays a PSD file. If it is enough to render and resize this image, it should be quite easy. If you want to resize groups of layers (some of which may contain non-pixel data), things get more complicated. Contrary to popular belief, [the PSD format is documented](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577409_89817) and not too hard to read if you only want pixel data.

Comment: Yes that I know, since that's exactly what the codeproject link I posted in the question itself does.

Comment: Great! Then you have a good starting point. ;-) If you look at the documentation I linked, it will also tell you how to parse layers, groups and the vector (path) information. But as you say, it will require some effort.

Comment: What about reproducing the Photoshop layer effects accurately? It's not like I am gonna do that myself... If there's no library, I can strictly forget about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, there seems to be no library to do what I want to do. Reading out the composite preview from PSD files is easy, as demonstrated in the codeproject link I posted in my question, but manipulating individual groups or layers, then rendering the composite preview again seems impossible for now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see is that Photoshop PSD files are *notoriously* difficult to read... see [this poor soul](http://codepad.org/DidDsbjF).

Also, the code you link to is from 2006 which pre-dates the current *"Smart Objects"* and real-time editing so I would doubt it will work for anything recent - though you may be fine if you only want to read some old files, or new uncomplicated ones of a specific project that doesn't use such features.

I would suggest you export the layers from Photoshop as PNGs and then work with that. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854858/photoshop-script-to-export-layer-combinations/29865961#29865961) might get you started.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of resizing. Resizing the PNGs will not look good because they are not vectors.

Comment: Oh, I see. Have you tried? Do you want to share a file and let me and other folks try resizing? Is your resizing that big? I just think you are barking up a pretty difficult tree to climb with trying to read PSD files. Also, why/how can Photoshop resize them if you can't? Is conversion to layered TIF maybe an option?

Comment: Well, I am not solely talking about images, but vectorial paths. And as you know, resizing a vector, then rendering it is not the same as rendering a vector, then resizing it.

Comment: Here's a demo of what I mean: http://ui-cloud.com/dark-velvet-ui-kit/ . Load it into Photoshop, then resize the elements - they'all always look good.

Comment: I'm not sure what I am supposed to be looking at on that website - I can't see a PSD file there...

Comment: But anyway, I think I can close this thread because I have searched the whole internet for a solution and I don't think there is one.